# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a form and if i submit the form with all the right data everything goes perfectly fine... but if I intentionally make any flaw

(validation for example `'title' => 'required|min:2'`)

and I put only one character for title or if I miss any required field I get this error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

[image]

I have figured out that the problem is with this select box

```
{!! Form::select('item[0][]', $items, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

and I even tried to use a normal select box without form helper {!! !!}

But I still get the same error!

So the problem is somewhere with validation when there is a nested array....is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you named your select box `item[0][]`? Can't it be simply `item`?

Comment: It cannot be a simple string...a user can add them dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I finally have an answer for this problem....it seems like something has changed in Laravel 5.3 and if you want to have a name with array like this

```
{!! Form::label('title', '* Eventname: ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('title[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required') !!}
```

You must put [0] something in brackets 'indices' like this:

```
{!! Form::text('title[0]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required') !!}
```

and then in validation use

title.*

for rule

UPDATE

Because i use dynamic form that can be expanded and new form fields added (optionally) i needed to put [] array notation for a name but actually if you already have hard coded many fields with the same name like item[] 
you don't have to put [0] indices inside. The validation will work for them.

The problem comes only if you have a single input field and you put [] array notation along the name for example `'item[]'`

this will trigger the error if any validation rule is broken...